# Failed to run thrift in hbase

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hbase, thrift

I have installed CygWin in my windows 7 and also installed hbase inside CygWin following instructions from official site. I am working with a project from which i need to connect to hbase database using it's thrift API. The project is python project and i have used happybase python module. The steps are first i need to run the hbase server and thrift api from CygWin shell. Then i connect to hbase using thrift api using happybase library. It was working fine but from yesterday the server is just running fine but when i try to run the thrift then the thrift is failed to run with the following message:

```
13/06/22 12:40:35 INFO util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.94.7
13/06/22 12:40:35 INFO util.VersionInfo: Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos
/asf/hbase/tags/0.94.7RC1 -r 1471806
13/06/22 12:40:35 INFO util.VersionInfo: Compiled by lhofhans on Wed Apr 24 18:4
8:26 PDT 2013
13/06/22 12:40:35 INFO thrift.ThriftServerRunner: Using default thrift server ty
pe
13/06/22 12:40:35 INFO thrift.ThriftServerRunner: Using thrift server type threa
dpool
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version
=3.4.5-1392090, built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=Sohel-P
C
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.
0
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracl
e Corporation
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=C:\Prog
ram Files\Java\jre7
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=C
:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\conf;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.j
ar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\
hbase-0.94.7.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\hbase-0.94.7-tests.jar;C:
\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\lo
cal\hbase-0.94.7\lib\asm-3.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\avro-
1.5.3.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar;C:\cygwin
\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\
local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local
\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\
commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-collecti
ons-3.2.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-configuration-1.
6.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\cygw
in\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\h
base-0.94.7\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7
\lib\commons-io-2.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-lang-2
.5.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\cy
gwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\loc
al\hbase-0.94.7\lib\commons-net-1.4.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\
lib\core-3.1.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:
\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr
\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-
0.94.7\lib\httpclient-4.1.2.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\httpco
re-4.1.3.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.ja
r;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar;C:\cygwin\ro
ot\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\lo
cal\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\
lib\jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jasper-com
piler-5.5.23.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jasper-runtime-5.5.23
.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jaxb-api-2.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\u
sr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0
.94.7\lib\jersey-core-1.8.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jersey-j
son-1.8.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jersey-server-1.8.jar;C:\c
ygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\
hbase-0.94.7\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jett
y-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jruby-complete-1.6.5
.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar;C:\cygwin\root
\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbas
e-0.94.7\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\junit-4.
10-HBASE-1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\libthrift-0.8.0.jar;C:\
cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local
\hbase-0.94.7\lib\metrics-core-2.1.2.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\l
ib\netty-3.2.4.Final.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\protobuf-java
-2.4.0a.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar;C:\cygwin\root\us
r\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-
0.94.7\lib\snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\sta
x-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\cy
gwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\lib\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hb
ase-0.94.7\lib\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;C:\cygwin\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.1\lib:
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path
=/usr/local/HBASE-~1.7/lib/native/Windows_7-x86-32
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:
\cygwin\root\tmp\
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA
>
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Windows 7

13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=x86
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=6.1
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=Sohel
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=C:\User
s\Sohel
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=C:\cygwi
n\root\usr\local\hbase-0.94.7\bin
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240000, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:35 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240000
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240000 closed
13/06/22 12:41:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240001, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:36 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240001
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240001 closed
13/06/22 12:41:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown
error)
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 12
7.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240002, negotiated timeou
t = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:37 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240002
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240002 closed
13/06/22 12:41:37 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown
error)
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 12
7.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240003, negotiated timeou
t = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:39 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240003
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240003 closed
13/06/22 12:41:39 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:41 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown
error)
13/06/22 12:41:41 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:41 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 12
7.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:42 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240004, negotiated timeou
t = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:42 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:42 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240004
13/06/22 12:41:42 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240004 closed
13/06/22 12:41:42 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240005, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:46 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240005
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240005 closed
13/06/22 12:41:46 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240006, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:50 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240006
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240006 closed
13/06/22 12:41:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240007, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:41:58 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240007
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:41:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240007 closed
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown
error)
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 12
7.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240008, negotiated timeou
t = 180000
13/06/22 12:42:14 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240008
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240008 closed
13/06/22 12:42:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/06/22 12:42:46 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connec
tString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this pr
ocess is 7944@Sohel-PC
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server
 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SA
SL (unknown error)
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:
0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on s
erver 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f6a9c77240009, negot
iated timeout = 180000
13/06/22 12:42:47 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Che
ck the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch w
ith the one configured in the master.
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Clos
ed zookeeper sessionid=0x13f6a9c77240009
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13f6a9c77240009 closed
13/06/22 12:42:47 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Re
tried 10 times
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:138)

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.<init>
(ThriftServerRunner.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner.<init>(ThriftServer
Runner.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.doMain(ThriftServer.java:
100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServer.main(ThriftServer.java:23
7)

Sohel@Sohel-PC /usr/local/hbase-0.94.7/bin
$
```

And the hbase-site.xml file is look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
 </property>
  <property>
     <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
     <value>file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/hbase/data</value>
     <description>The directory shared by region servers.
     Should be fully-qualified to include the filesystem to use.
     E.g: hdfs://NAMENODE_SERVER:PORT/HBASE_ROOTDIR
     </description>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>C:/cygwin/tmp/hbase/tmp</value>
     <description>Temporary directory on the local filesystem.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Please help me with this issue guys.

Thanks,
Codengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property in your hbase-site.xml and restart HBase :

```
<property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<value>file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/hbase/data</value>
</property>
```

This is the root ZNode for HBase in ZooKeeper. All of HBase's ZooKeeper files will go under this node. It defaults to `/hbase` if not changed and you are using `/hbase/data`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have added this node to my hbase-site.xml file. Then i have restarted hbase. This time when i opened hbase shell and run a simple command list the shell replies "ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must start with / character". Could you please help me with this also.

Comment: You are most welcome. Looks like java issue to me. I would recommend you to use java-6(sun) in case you are using some other jdk.

Comment: ok Tariq thanks a lot. Finally i am able to connect the thrift to hbase but this time if i remove the znode.parent node from hbase-site.xml and restart my hbase it also works just fine. So many thanks for the help. You guys are really great!